# MediaRecorder: setCamera() - error camera is not aviable

Tags: java, android, camera, mediarecorder

Anyone know how to using it for mediarecorder ?
im using

recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface)  where holder - it's camera ( i see chest rectangle on my screen of phone) 
When i runn my app - in logcat i see error  (camera is not aviable) im try to using function 
setCamera - but it's not help me. 
Anyone know how to right use it ?

or maybe  i can record video(only video, without audio) some other way?

ok SOLVED

this code for example

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        camera.unlock();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you forgot to set the permissions on your android manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Now I read you have already answered it.

Don't forget to write is as an answer.

The solution would be:

```
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
camera.unlock();
mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
```