# Android MediaRecorder causes Force Stop error

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdcard, android-mediarecorder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MediaRecorder: setCamera() - error camera is not aviable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886532/mediarecorder-setcamera-error-camera-is-not-aviable)

I am making an application that allows a user to record audio and save it somewhere in the SD card. I am using a MediaRecorder to do record the audio.

I am reusing some of the code from the androiddevblog website as it was recommended by another user on stackoverflow to check those tutorials.

My problem is whenever I click the button to record audio I get an error saying "Your Application has been forced to stop". I have posted my code for the recording feature below.

EDIT: I solved my original problem. Now when I add recorder.stop() to my code I get an illegalStateException. I have updated the code below as well(The only changes are in the startRecorder method). Any ideas ?

I am aware that nothing will get recorded based on my code. I want to first make sure the file gets created and saved.

```
public class MyRecorderActivity extends Activity{

private Button audio;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.questionandanswer);
....
....

 audio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.audio_recordactivity);
    audio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

        startRecording();


        }
    });

 } 

  private String getFilename(){
        String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File file = new File(filepath,AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);

        if(!file.exists()){
                file.mkdirs();
        }

        return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/");
  }

 private void startRecording(){
        MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();

        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());

        try {
                recorder.prepare();
                recorder.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

        recorder.stop();
        recorder.reset();
        recorder.release();
   }

}
```

Comment: what are using emulator or an android device?

Comment: I think there needs to be an automated reminder to post a LogCat if the post includes the words "force" and "close". @AndroidDev93, check your LogCat to see *what* exception is being thrown and where. If that doesn't help you figure out the problem, edit the log into your question.

Comment: @K_Anas - I am using an ASUS Transformer tablet. Not an emulator.

Comment: @kcoppock - I haven't used the log cat much since I am just learning android now. But, from what I see the log cat says : setAudioSource Failed. There are a lot of other red entries. Are they also required to understand the problem ?

Comment: @AndroidDev93: The red area is the stack trace for the exception that was thrown. You should look down the list (starting from the top) until you reach a line that mentions one of your .java files. It'll then say something like (MyFile.java: 34) where MyFile is the name of your document, and 34 is the line of code in which the exception is occurring. I can tell it's the second line in your `startRecording()` method, though. Have you requested the RECORD_AUDIO permission in your manifest?

Comment: That was my problem. I used the debugger to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: @AndroidDev93 Write up your comment as an answer then mark it as 'answered' so others can see your question has a result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I forgot to add the permissions!